# Hidden Div not showing after some time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a `div` with a class name as `startab`, which is `hidden` by default. I want to show it after `5s` of `page load`.

I tried using `javascript` but it didn't display.

```
<style>
.startab {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(".startab").delay(5000).show();
</script>
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/euqvepdw/)

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Your script is not vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @ACJ I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/euqvepdw/4/) that too, but then also it didn't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your `javascript` with [`seTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".startab").show()},5000);
```

Also, add a library to it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/euqvepdw/2)

Comment: The `delay` function is fine once you load jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout for that.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $("#test").show();
}, 5000);
```

```css
#test {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

The code is waiting for the page to be loaded, then running the script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".startab").show();
    },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler solution using jQuery. Simply pass duration 0 to show:

```
$(".startab")
    .delay(5000)
    .show(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".startab").show();
}, 5000);
```

And your css will be

```
.startab{
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all looks like you have not included the jquery.

And in script you don't need to use delay, you can directly say like..

`$('.startab').show(5000)`

Comment: That would make the element fade in over the course of 5 seconds.

Comment: Yeah my mistake.. then using this `$('.startab').delay(5000).fadeIn(0)` better than using setTimeOut, If show is not working out